# Sequentioal requests with Mojo::IOLoop::Delay

Tags: perl, asynchronous, mojolicious

I need to get list of URLs in non-blocking mode, but not in parallel. It should be sequential requests one by one. How can I realize that?

I cannot find examples. Documentation and articles highlight only parallel execution.

Now my code looks like the following (simplified):

```
my $delay = Mojo::IOLoop::Delay->new;

$delay->steps(
    sub {
        build_report();
        say "done";
    }
);

sub parse_data {
    ...;
    my $url = shift @urls;
    my $end = $delay->begin;
    $ua->get( $url => \&parse_data );
    $end->();
}

my $end = $delay->begin;
$ua->get( $url => \&parse_data );
$end->();
$delay->wait;
```

I want to avoid multiple closures by using [`Mojo::IOLoop::Delay`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::IOLoop::Delay).

Comment: What is `$ua`? And what does `build_report` do?

Comment: $ua is Mojo::UserAgent; build_report collects data from all requests in a summary report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just started looking at `Mojo::IOLoop` myself for a project and I'm not au fait with it yet. But I think the simplest way is to build an array of closures and pass it to `$delay->steps`.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Mojo;

use constant URL => 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl';

STDOUT->autoflush;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $delay = Mojo::IOLoop::Delay->new;

my @urls = ( URL ) x 10;

my @steps =  map {

    my $url = $_;

    sub {

        my $end = $delay->begin;

        $ua->get( $url => sub {
            my ( $ua, $txn ) = @_;

            $end->();

            if ( my $err = $txn->error ) {
                say $err->message;
            }
            else {
                my $res = $txn->success;
                say "@{$res}{qw/ code message /}";
            }
        });
    }

} @urls;


$delay->steps( @steps, sub { say 'Done' } );

Mojo::IOLoop->start unless Mojo::IOLoop->is_running;
```

#### output

```
200 OK
200 OK
200 OK
200 OK
200 OK
200 OK
200 OK
200 OK
200 OK
Done
200 OK
```

Note that `Done` is printed before the status line of the final `get`, because I have called `$end->()` immediately the callback arrives, assuming that any handling of the response doesn't need to be synchronised

If you don't want that then just move `$end->()` to the end of the callback. Then the delay will wait until the output has been generated before sending another request

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Sequential requests very easy to implement.

**Web server**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Mojo::Base -strict;

use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/' => sub {
  my $c = shift->render_later;

  $c->delay(sub {
    my $delay = shift;
    $c->ua->get('https://google.ru' => $delay->begin);
  }, sub {
    my ($delay, $tx) = @_;
    $tx->res->body; # body of the google.ru
    $c->ua->get('https://twitter.com' => $delay->begin);
  }, sub {
    my ($delay, $tx) = @_;
    $tx->res->body; # body of the twitter.com
    $c->render(text => 'Done');
  });
};

app->start;
```

**Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Mojo::Base -strict;

use Mojo::IOLoop;
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

Mojo::IOLoop->delay(sub {
  my $delay = shift;
  $ua->get('https://www.google.ru' => $delay->begin);
}, sub {
  my ($delay, $tx) = @_;
  $tx->res->body; # body of the google.ru
  $ua->get('https://twitter.com' => $delay->begin);
}, sub {
  my ($delay, $tx) = @_;
  $tx->res->body; # body of the twitter.com
  warn 'DONE';
})->wait;
```

**Script** (dynamic requests)

[Example here](https://gist.github.com/Logioniz/4c2ffcbb2e997814e63544387bec2ee2)

Comment: It's OK, but I do not know how many URLs will be in list. I have to add subs in delay() dynamically. I could not find how to do it.

Comment: I update post to add example, but i think that code may looks more pretty if you will do closure without delay.

Comment: I have to used delay because it's web server and it should return answer immediately. So, it should be asynchronous gets. Your example under link is the same as my code. I do not like it.

Comment: Delay not allow you to perform requests immediately. Delay need to write code sequentially. So you need simply remove delay, because code without it look more clear. I update my gist to add 2 example: without delay and another with delay. Click on example again!

Comment: **callback.dynamic.sequential.pl** looks very pretty, but where should I place final function build_report()? It should summarize all requests to one order.